# Getting "undefined" when trying to access an object property in javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm creating a leaflet map for showing agencies on the map, with markers created dynamically for each agency. Also there is list of agencies which when clicked on each one, the map zooms automatically on the specific marker for that agency. Now I intend to show some agency info inside of a popup on every marker, but this popup shows only when clicked upon the agency card or the marker itself. I've been successful in the latter and popups show when clicked on the markers. But I'm having problems when trying to achieve this by clicking on the agency cards.
So, in order to clarify the problem, the path I've chosen is as below:

First, my html code for cards:

```
 <div class="card border border-secondary rounded" onclick="moveMap({{ agency.latitude }}, {{ agency.longitude }}, {{ agency.id }})" style="cursor: pointer; z-index: 1000">
... // rest of the html code
```

Since my backend is on django, so I'm using `{{}}`s.

In the `moveMap()` function, I'm sending `agency.latitude`, `agency.longitude` and `agency.id`, and my javascript code is as below:

```
function moveMap(lat, long, id) {
    map.flyTo([lat, long], 14, {
      animate: true,
      duration: 3.5,
    });
    openPopupByID(id);
}
```

Here, after moving map to the proper marker, I'm calling `openPopupById()` function, which takes `id` as it's parameter, and the `openPopupById()` function is as below:

```
function openPopupByID (agency_id) {
    for (let item in markerList) {
        if (item["id"] === agency_id) {
            item.openPopup();
        }
    }
}
```

In this function I'm using `markerList` which is created as below:

```
let markerList = [];

// creating markers using the coorList
for (let dataSet of coorList) {
     let latNumber = parseFloat(dataSet[0]);
     let longNumber = parseFloat(dataSet[1]);
     let marker = L.marker(L.latLng(latNumber, longNumber)).addTo(map);

     // listing agency info inside popups
     marker.bindPopup(setMarkerInfo(dataSet[2]));

     //adding each marker to the markerList
     marker["id"] = dataSet[2];
     markerList.push(marker);
}
```

`coorList` is a list of arrays with three values, `agency.latitude`, `agency.longitude` and `agency.id` with indexes of 0, 1 and 2.

So I have a `markerList` which is list of marker objects, and with `marker["id"] = dataSet[2];` I've added an `id` property to the `marker` object.
But in `openPopupByID()` function, when I'm trying to access the `id` of a marker, I'm getting `undefined` message from js console.
When I tried to see the structure of the `markerList` using `console.log(markerList)`, I get the following:
[image]

In which we can clearly see the `id` property.

So, what is my problem? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please add the exact error. It's not clear what is undefined here

Comment: try `for...of` instead of `for...in` .... the former will give you a bunch of indices when performed on an Array, the latter will give you each item in an Array

Comment: @JaromandaX That was it :) as simple as that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @adiga The undefined error was shown when I was trying to console.log(item["id"]). Nothing more was written, just an undefined message in the console tab in chrome developer tools. If you have given a downvote because of this, please upvote or at least remove your downvote if possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I haven't downvoted ([Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686))

Comment: I am sorry if I offended you but I didn't assume it was you surely, just since you pointed out that I should've written the complete error message, I asked if it was you. Frankly, I tried to write this question as well-explained as I could, I did explain what I did in every step and what was the outcome, but yet it got 2 downvotes :(. It just bothers me a bit to receive downvotes without knowing what is the cause of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using for..of instead of for..in

```
function openPopupByID (agency_id) {
    for (let item of markerList) {
        console.log('test -- ', item.id, item);
        if (item["id"] === agency_id) {
            item.openPopup();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **for of** loop for array instead of **for in** loop which is used for objects.

**for in** loop will check if id is present in markerList instead of the each element in the list

source - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

```js
function openPopupByID (agency_id) {
    for (let item of markerList) {
        if (item["id"] === agency_id) {
            item.openPopup();
        }
    }
}
```